# How to set a program to run in Linux terminal only with program name

Tags: linux, unix

I'm new to Linux and I wonder there are many programs we can use only program name to start it in Linux terminal, like `gedit`,`vi`,`firefox` instead of providing the all program's path,I like to run my own programs like this in terminal only typing program name, programs I like to run are written in `Java` and `Python` (`.jar`, `.pyc`, `.py` and `.class`)

I like to know how to do it with step by step

Comment: `echo $PATH` on your shell. That is where it looks. Maybe put symlinks to the executables in `/usr/local/bin` with whatever name you want.

Comment: @dilee - If any of the answers help, please upvote and accept the answer. I think both of the answers are good, and you must upvote them at least. If you've any issue with them, please discuss with the original answerer below their answer in the form of a comment!

Answer (score 1):

You can write whatever program/script you have to behave as a command. Let's say your `executable script/program` is named as `my_script` and is placed in `/path/to/my_script`.

Be sure that the script is executable. If not,then please do

```
chmod +x /path/to/my_script
```

Then, place a symlink to this location in `/usr/local/bin` as

```
sudo ln -s /path/to/my_script /usr/local/bin
```

You can add the symlink to any of the paths mentioned in `$PATH`.

That's it and enjoy your program.

Comment: @Goddard-If that's wrong,I'll do for the sake of future audience. I don't care downvotes on my answer till it's correct.

Comment: You have been doing this long enough.  That was just a jerk move.

Comment: BTW, there's no need to reboot.

Comment: @amenadiel- Agree,was thinking something about `.bashrc` file,hence,mistakenly wrote that. Thanks for correcting.

Comment: Yes you down voted me for no reason.  Pretty messed up.

Comment: @Goddard-SORRY,but,I already have mentioned the reason. You haven't provided the exact reason,your answer seems clumsy. It seems you yourself are confused! What's the need of exporting directory to `$PATH`---useless and vague idea. Next, even if you'd have used the idea,you should have added the case, when it's not being added to any of the pre-defined PATH locations as shown by `$PATH`! Please clarify OR better improve your answer. I'm ready to remove my downvote,only if you improve.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers all involve creating a symlink in a directory that is already listed in the system PATH, but I think it is more unixy to add needed directories to your PATH.

If your script is located at `$HOME/bin/myscript` and you have already made sure that it is executable then you can run

```
export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
```

to run it without giving the full path. And you can add that same line to your `.bashrc` file in your home directory to have it preloaded whenever you start your shell.  This approach does not require that the user has permission to create symlinks in system directories.

Answer (score -1):

If you have an executable binary file in your home folder (let's say for example `sublime_text`) you must give it execute permision and call it with its relative path

```
chmod +x sublime_text
./sublime_text
```

If you made a symlink to it in **/usr/bin** (or other folders included in your `PATH`), you would be able to call it by its name

```
sudo ln -s ~/sublime_text /usr/bin/sublime_text
sublime_text
```

In your case, you aren't dealing with binary files, but with scripts meant to be interpreted. For this you must prepend a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) telling linux what's the binary meant to execute the script. If it was, for example, a python script `~/hello.py`, these could be the contents of the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print "Hello, World!"
```

Where the first line tells linux to use the python binary to execute the script.

From then on, you can do:

```
chmod +x hello.py
sudo ln -s ~/hello.py /usr/bin/hello
hello
```

And it will echo "Hello World" to the console.